# Switch prefreence along with preference headers in preference activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, android-switch

```
    I am trying to create a page with few preference Headers and a Switch preference. I have tried two ways to get switch button on page along with preference headers.

    First attempt:

    xml file 


    <preference-headers
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Header1 -->
    <header
        android:id="@+id/Header1"
        android:fragment="com.android.Headers.header1"
        android:title="@string/Header1"


    <!-- Header2 -->
    <header
        android:id="@+id/Header2"
        android:fragment="com.android.Headers.header2"
        android:title="@string/Header2"

   <!-- Header3-->
    <header
        android:id="@+id/Header3"
        android:title="@string/Header3" /> 

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="PromoNotificationOnOff"
        android:title="@string/Snotification_enable" /> 
</preference-headers>`
```

Loaded the headers here

```
 public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> headers) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.headers, headers);
```

this didnt show any switch in the page

Second attempt:

Divided Headers and switch into two Xml files.

Loaded the headers using

```
 public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> headers) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.headers, headers);
```

and added the switchpref.xml in oncreate method using addPreferencesFromResource.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.switchpref);


}
```

It crashed the app.

Please let me know the way to create the headers and switch preference in a single page and accessing Switch button information.